# Downloading files in a loop with Python mechanize

Tags: python, loops, download, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am having trouble downloading multiple files in a loop with Python mechanize. I am also utilizing Beautiful Soup 4. The documentation for either package does not seem to have the answers.

Here is my code - please skip down to the actual loop. I included everything for reference:

```
import mechanize, cookielib, os, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


fcList = ['abandoned mine land inventory points', 'abandoned mine land inventory polygons', \
          'abandoned mine land inventory sites', 'coal mining operations', 'coal pillar location-mining', \
          'industrial mineral mining operations', 'longwall mining panels', 'mine drainage treatment/land recycling project locations', \
          'mined out areas', 'residual waste operations', 'underground mining permit']

dlLink = 'FTP Download'
dloadPath = 'C:\\Users\\SomeGuy\\Downloads'

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Select the first (index zero) form
br.select_form(nr=0)

# Input form data
br.form['Keyword']='mining'
br.submit()
html = br.response().read()

# Pass html to beautiful soup for parse
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
htmlinks = soup.findAll("a")

# Find links with desired text
for htmlink in htmlinks:
    string = str(htmlink.string)
    if string.lower() in fcList:
        print "Matched link!", string + ". attempting download...\n"
        try:
            req = br.click_link(text = string)
            br.open(req)
            print "URL: " + str(br.geturl)
            html = br.response().read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
            the_tag = soup.find('a', text=dlLink)
            fileURL = the_tag.get('href')
            print fileURL
            # attempt download
            fnam = string.replace(" ", "_")
            fnam = fnam.replace("/", "_")
            f = br.retrieve(fileURL, os.path.join(dloadPath, fnam + ".zip"))
            print f + "\n"
            br.back()
        except:
            print "An unknown error occurred."
```

Output:

```
>>> 
Matched link! Abandoned Mine Land Inventory Points. attempting download...

URL: <bound method Browser.geturl of <mechanize._mechanize.Browser instance at 0x02D9D7B0>>
http://www.pasda.psu.edu/data/dep/AMLInventoryPoints2013_04.zip
An unknown error occurred.
Matched link! Abandoned Mine Land Inventory Polygons. attempting download...

An unknown error occurred.
Matched link! Abandoned Mine Land Inventory Sites. attempting download...

An unknown error occurred.
Matched link! Coal Mining Operations. attempting download...

An unknown error occurred.
Matched link! Coal Pillar Location-Mining. attempting download...

An unknown error occurred.
Matched link! Industrial Mineral Mining Operations. attempting download...

An unknown error occurred.
Matched link! Longwall Mining Panels. attempting download...

An unknown error occurred.
Matched link! Mine Drainage Treatment/Land Recycling Project Locations. attempting     download...

An unknown error occurred.
Matched link! Mined Out Areas. attempting download...

An unknown error occurred.
Matched link! Residual Waste Operations. attempting download...

An unknown error occurred.
Matched link! Underground Mining Permit. attempting download...

An unknown error occurred.
>>>
```

I believe the problem could be due to having no wait time between downloads. This code will download the very first file in the loop successfully, no matter which one I choose. Or perhaps it's some other bug I am not aware of- I just downloaded mechanize and beautifulsoup yesterday!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f = br.retrieve(fileURL, os.path.join(dloadPath, fnam + ".zip"))[0]
```

If this wont work, remove `try..catch` and post what actual error are you getting

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the long delay... I will try this and get back to you ASAP! I thought this would never get a reply. It was my first question on here and I did not ask it very well.